# How to do an irregular mosaic of images with different sizes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, layout

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve :

[image: example of mosaic of images]

**context** : I would like to use HTML5/CSS3 to create a mosaic of a bunch of related images. They should have no margin (unlike the example, pardon my Paint :D ) and their sizes are various, but I would need them to be "intricate", so that it makes a single scrollable block of clickable images. Please note it is possible to use Javascript if needed.

*How should I go with displaying such a layout ?*

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html#responsive-layouts does this fit your requirements?

Comment: This looks like what you want, https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/ but unless you know what images you have and their sizes you're not likely to get this done in JUST html/css/Javascript.  I don't think it's possible to view a directory listing with ajax anyway

Comment: @dstarh there block is obviously divided in columns, I could do that but it wouldn't make the desired effect of it being "random" :/

Comment: @godblessstrawberry this looks good even though the images width/length seem to be a multiple of a base size, I'd prefer not to but if I have no choice then I'll use this :) thank you

Comment: @Magix good luck with that)

Comment: @Magix the point you seem to be missing is the "undefined amount of images" You'll need to know the dimensions of said images.   You'll need to know the existence of the images as well and given that they're "undefined" as you stated how are you even going to know the images are there?  Will you have an array of the images and their dimensions?

Comment: This is doable, or I can AJAX some server-side script to ask for the names and sizes of images, or straight generate the JS using PHP or such, but this is not the point. I would like to know how to display this, so to simplify, let's say I do have an array of names and sizes, if it helps ! :)

Comment: The question has been edited to be less broad, please re-open it and flag this comment as obsolete if it is better now :)